# C# question mark operator postfixed to cast

Tags: c#, operators

I was looking at the [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) page and saw this terse bit of coding:

```
   new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

What does `(int?)null` do?

Could someone please elucidate what is going on there, and perhaps give a more "verbose" version of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`. as such this line of code is converting null (which by default is of type `object`) to a null int.

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: As the earliest answer, and one that also contains a link to the docs for my further reading, I will give this one the answer-check. The other answers were also elucidating, Albin's for expanding the shorthand, Serge's for "anonymous type" and the explanation about `null`, and Anton's for the further explanation about how the compiler infers the type of Age. Thanks again, all.

Answer (score 2):

If all you have is `new { Age = null }`, compiler has no way of knowing what is the exact type of `Age`. So "casting" `null` to `Nullable<Int32>` effectively tells it that `Age` property is of that type.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx): The type of `Age` must be implied from the value assigned to it. `null` can be any nullable type. The cast specify the type that `Age` should have: `int?` (aka `Nullable<int>`)

Answer (score 1):

`?` marks a [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) int

It is a syntactical shorhand for `((System.Nullable<int>)null)`.